# how to make awk print everything from nth column

Tags: bash, awk

I have this line in a bash script which prints a modified output of the list of every installed command :

```
    # with the awk command :

    $ apropos -s ${SECTION:-''} ${@:-.} | grep -v -E '^.+ \(0\)' | awk '{print $2 "    " $1}' | sort | head
    (1)    [
    (1)    2to3-2.7
    (1)    411toppm
    (1)    7z
    (1)    7za
    (1)    7zr
    (1)    aa-enabled
    (1)    aa-exec
    (1)    aclocal
    (1)    aclocal-1.16

    # without the awk command : (running a french system)

    $ apropos -s ${SECTION:-''} ${@:-.} | grep -v -E '^.+ \(0\)' | sort | head
    [ (1)                - Vérifier le type d'un fichier, et comparer des valeurs
    2048-qt (6)          - the 2048 number game implemented in Qt
    2to3-2.7 (1)         - Python2 to Python3 converter
    30-systemd-environment-d-generator (8) - Load variables specified by environment.d
    411toppm (1)         - convert Sony Mavica .411 image to ppm
    7z (1)               - A file archiver with high compression ratio format
    7za (1)              - A file archiver with high compression ratio format
    7zr (1)              - A file archiver with high compression ratio format
    a64l (3)             - Fonctions de conversion entre les types long et base 64
    aa-enabled (1)       - test whether AppArmor is enabled
```

The awk command prints the name of each command preceded by its category (between the parentheses). Now I want it to print every thing from the category (second column) to the end, so the output looks like :

```
    $ command
    (1)    [             - description
    (1)    2to3-2.7      - description
    (1)    411toppm      - description
    (1)    7z            - description
    (1)    7za           - description
    (1)    7zr           - description
    (1)    aa-enabled    - description
    (1)    aa-exec       - description
    (1)    aclocal       - description
    (1)    aclocal-1.16  - description
```

I tried with the following but I got this :

```
    apropos -s ${SECTION:-''} ${@:-.} | grep -v -E '^.+ \(0\)' | awk -v n=$2 '{$2=""; print n "    " $0}' | sort | head
        2048-qt  - the 2048 number game implemented in Qt
        2to3-2.7  - Python2 to Python3 converter
        30-systemd-environment-d-generator  - Load variables specified by environment.d
        411toppm  - convert Sony Mavica .411 image to ppm
        7za  - A file archiver with high compression ratio format
        7z  - A file archiver with high compression ratio format
        7zr  - A file archiver with high compression ratio format
        a64l  - Fonctions de conversion entre les types long et base 64
        aa-enabled  - test whether AppArmor is enabled
        aa-exec  - confine a program with the specified AppArmor profile
```

=> I'd like to have the category at the begining of each line and a nice tabbing for the description as I showed above. I think the problem with the tabbing is that $0 contains only the columns and not the entire line.

===

edit : this is how looks like `apropos -s ${SECTION:-''} ${@:-.}` (only the begining because it's more than 8,000 lines)

```
    $ apropos -s ${SECTION:-''} ${@:-.} | head -n40
    iwconfig (8)         - configure une interface réseau sans-fil (wireless)
    iwevent (8)          - Display Wireless Events generated by drivers and setting changes
    iwgetid (8)          - Report ESSID, NWID or AP/Cell Address of wireless network
    iwlist (8)           - Get more detailed wireless information from a wireless interface
    iwpriv (8)           - configure optionals (private) parameters of a wireless network ...
    iwspy (8)            - Get wireless statistics from specific nodes
    wireless (7)         - Wireless Tools et Wireless Extensions
    adduser.conf (5)     - Fichier de configuration d'adduser(8) etaddgroup(8).
    deluser.conf (5)     - Fichier de configuration de deluser(8) etdelgroup(8).
    hosts.equiv (5)      - Liste d'hôtes et d'utilisateurs ayant l'autorisation d'accéde...
    modules (5)          - modules du noyau à charger au démarrage
    slabinfo (5)         - Statistiques de l'allocateur slab du noyau
    des (3SSL)           - Chiffrement DES
    dnsmasq (8)          - Un serveur DHCP et cache DNS poids-plume.
    _newselect (2)       - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
    FD_CLR (3)           - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
    FD_ISSET (3)         - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
    FD_SET (3)           - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
    FD_ZERO (3)          - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
    faked (1)            - démon qui mémorise les permissions et propriétaires factices...
    hmac (3SSL)          - message d'authentification de message HMAC
    md5 (3SSL)           - Fonctions de hachage MD2, MD4 et MD5
    mdc2 (3SSL)          - Fonction de hachage MDC2
    NAN (3)              - Constantes en virgule flottante
    pem (3SSL)           - routines PEM
    printf (1)           - Formater et afficher des données
    rc4 (3SSL)           - chiffrement RC4
    ripemd (3SSL)        - Fonction de hachage RIPEMD-160
    sha (3SSL)           - Algorithme de hachage sécurisé (« Secure Hash Algorithm »)
    ssl (3SSL)           - Bibliothèque SSL/TLS OpenSSL
    utf8 (7)             - Codage Unicode multioctet compatible ASCII
    unicode (7)          - Jeu de caractères universel
    [ (1)                - Vérifier le type d'un fichier, et comparer des valeurs
    _Exit (2)            - Mettre fin au processus appelant
    __after_morecore_hook (3) - Variables de débogage de malloc.
    __clone2 (2)         - Créer un processus fils (child)
    __fbufsize (3)       - Interfaces pour la structure FILE (stdio)
    __flbf (3)           - Interfaces pour la structure FILE (stdio)
    __fpending (3)       - Interfaces pour la structure FILE (stdio)
    __fpurge (3)         - Purger un flux
```

===

2nd edit : I want it to print every thing from the category (second column) to the end, so the output looks like :

```
    $ command
    (1)    [             - description
    (1)    2to3-2.7      - description
    (1)    411toppm      - description
    (1)    7z            - description
    (1)    7za           - description
    (1)    7zr           - description
    (1)    aa-enabled    - description
    (1)    aa-exec       - description
    (1)    aclocal       - description
    (1)    aclocal-1.16  - description
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in form of code in your question. Could you please post sample output of `apropos -s ${SECTION:-''} ${@:-.}` in your question and let us know clearly sample expected output too, kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I pasted its begining because it takes more than 8,000 lines

Comment: Thank you for doing so, could you please do let us know sample expected output, you have output coming out fro your commands if you could mention clear expected sample final output in your question and let us know. I am sorry if I missed something but not clear to me as of now, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for me, I already put there what I expect : it's the second code block which starts with `$ command`. I'm really sorry if it's not clear.... I'll try to clean it. ====== Now the last block is also what I want.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove all the stuff we don't need to know about and just provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (output of `apropos`), the expected final output given that input, and the command you've tried so far. Right now you have 6 separate blocks of text (as opposed to 2 - 1 input and 1 output) and multiple commands so it's very hard to tell input from output and determine what it is you actually are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

See the following example:

```
[STEP 107] # cat file
hmac (3SSL)          - message d'authentification de message HMAC
md5 (3SSL)           - Fonctions de hachage MD2, MD4 et MD5
mdc2 (3SSL)          - Fonction de hachage MDC2
NAN (3)              - Constantes en virgule flottante
pem (3SSL)           - routines PEM
printf (1)           - Formater et afficher des données
rc4 (3SSL)           - chiffrement RC4
ripemd (3SSL)        - Fonction de hachage RIPEMD-160
[STEP 108] # awk '{ t=$1; s=$2; $1=""; $2=""; printf("%-8s%-11s%s\n", s, t, $0); }' file
(3SSL)  hmac         - message d'authentification de message HMAC
(3SSL)  md5          - Fonctions de hachage MD2, MD4 et MD5
(3SSL)  mdc2         - Fonction de hachage MDC2
(3)     NAN          - Constantes en virgule flottante
(3SSL)  pem          - routines PEM
(1)     printf       - Formater et afficher des données
(3SSL)  rc4          - chiffrement RC4
(3SSL)  ripemd       - Fonction de hachage RIPEMD-160
[STEP 109] #
```

You may need to adjust the column width accordingly as in `%-8s%-11s`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on OP's shown samples only, could you please try following written in GNU `awk`.

```
your_command | awk '
match($0,/\([^)]*\)/){
  printf("%-8s%-11s%s\n",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),substr($0,1,RSTART-1),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

- Using `match` function to match mentioned regex. In regex mentioning `/\([^)]*\)/` which will match everything from `(` to till first occurrence of `)` with `)` in current line.
- Whenever there is a TRUE match found for mentioned regex in `awk`'s `match` function then it sets 2 more default variables named `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`. Where `RSTART` contains value of matched regex's position number and `RLENGTH` contains full length of matched regex in it.
- Now simply using print to print the sub-string, where first `substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)` will print matched regex. `substr($0,1,RSTART-1)` prints from 1st position to till 1 lesser than `RSTART` position and `substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)` will print rest of the line after matched regex value.

***PS:*** `printf` `%s` values are taken from @pynexj's nice code.

Comment: tried and the result is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sGPo.png).

Comment: @pynexj,oh you are talking about spaces?(if yes) then I am still not very sure about OP's exact output so I made it same as Input only.

Comment: yes. space and alignment  would make it look better. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use perl. Given your sample apropos output, this:

```sh
apropos ... | perl -pe 's/^(.+?)(\(.*?\))/ sprintf "%-6s %-*s", $2, length($1.$2), $1 /e'
```

outputs this

```
(8)    iwconfig             - configure une interface réseau sans-fil (wireless)
(8)    iwevent              - Display Wireless Events generated by drivers and setting changes
(8)    iwgetid              - Report ESSID, NWID or AP/Cell Address of wireless network
(8)    iwlist               - Get more detailed wireless information from a wireless interface
(8)    iwpriv               - configure optionals (private) parameters of a wireless network ...
(8)    iwspy                - Get wireless statistics from specific nodes
(7)    wireless             - Wireless Tools et Wireless Extensions
(5)    adduser.conf         - Fichier de configuration d'adduser(8) etaddgroup(8).
(5)    deluser.conf         - Fichier de configuration de deluser(8) etdelgroup(8).
(5)    hosts.equiv          - Liste d'hôtes et d'utilisateurs ayant l'autorisation d'accéde...
(5)    modules              - modules du noyau à charger au démarrage
(5)    slabinfo             - Statistiques de l'allocateur slab du noyau
(3SSL) des                  - Chiffrement DES
(8)    dnsmasq              - Un serveur DHCP et cache DNS poids-plume.
(2)    _newselect           - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
(3)    FD_CLR               - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
(3)    FD_ISSET             - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
(3)    FD_SET               - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
(3)    FD_ZERO              - Multiplexage d'entrées-sorties synchrones
(1)    faked                - démon qui mémorise les permissions et propriétaires factices...
(3SSL) hmac                 - message d'authentification de message HMAC
(3SSL) md5                  - Fonctions de hachage MD2, MD4 et MD5
(3SSL) mdc2                 - Fonction de hachage MDC2
(3)    NAN                  - Constantes en virgule flottante
(3SSL) pem                  - routines PEM
(1)    printf               - Formater et afficher des données
(3SSL) rc4                  - chiffrement RC4
(3SSL) ripemd               - Fonction de hachage RIPEMD-160
(3SSL) sha                  - Algorithme de hachage sécurisé (« Secure Hash Algorithm »)
(3SSL) ssl                  - Bibliothèque SSL/TLS OpenSSL
(7)    utf8                 - Codage Unicode multioctet compatible ASCII
(7)    unicode              - Jeu de caractères universel
(1)    [                    - Vérifier le type d'un fichier, et comparer des valeurs
(2)    _Exit                - Mettre fin au processus appelant
(3)    __after_morecore_hook     - Variables de débogage de malloc.
(2)    __clone2             - Créer un processus fils (child)
(3)    __fbufsize           - Interfaces pour la structure FILE (stdio)
(3)    __flbf               - Interfaces pour la structure FILE (stdio)
(3)    __fpending           - Interfaces pour la structure FILE (stdio)
(3)    __fpurge             - Purger un flux
```